# C++ setting floating point exception environment

Tags: c++, gcc, sigfpe, fenv

I'm struggling trying to set the std::fenv in a portable way.

Based on [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) cppreference page, it seems that `fesetexceptflag(const std::fexcept_t*,int)` should help me do the trick. On the other hand, I found out that GNU offers also the `feenableexcept(int)` function. My understanding is that `feenablexcept` is GNU specific, and, although I'm *highly* likely to always have access to GNU stuff, I was hoping to just use std stuff, that is, stick with `fesetexceptflag`.
I wrote a little test, and found out that the `feenableexcept` approach works, while the `fesetexceptflag` one doesn't. Here are the two examples. Swap comments in the two lines at the beginning of main to obtain version 1 (`fesetexceptflag`) and version 2 (`feenableexcept`):

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>

void signal_handler (int signum) {
  printf ("signal %d caught.\n",signum);
  exit(1);
}

int main(int,char**){
  std::fexcept_t my_flag = FE_DIVBYZERO;
  fesetexceptflag(&my_flag,FE_ALL_EXCEPT); // Uncomment this for version 1
  // feenableexcept(my_flag); // Uncomment this for version 2

  int mask = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)
  printf("current mask: %d\n",mask);
  printf("mask is FE_DIVBYZERO: %s\n",mask==FE_DIVBYZERO ? "yes" : "no");
  signal(SIGFPE, signal_handler);

  double one  = 1.0;
  double zero = 0.0;
  double my_inf = one/zero;
  printf("All done!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Version 1 output:

```
current mask: 4
mask is FE_DIVBYZERO: yes
All done!
```

Version 2 output:

```
current mask: 0
mask is FE_DIVBYZERO: no
signal 8 caught.
```

So it seems that version 1 sets the exception flags correctly in the fenv, but fails to raise SIGFPE, while version 2 does not set the exception flags, but does raise SIGFPE. What's happening here? Am I misinterpreting the documentation of `fesetexceptflag`? My understanding was that it grabs all bits in the first arg that are active in the second arg, and puts them in the fenv (which is what seems to happen). But then, it seems ineffective. On the other hand, version 2 has a 0 mask fenv, and yet succeeds in raising SIGFPE. I'm very confused.

I'm using gcc 8.2.0 on a linux machine (Red Hat), if that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I misinterpreting the documentation of fesetexceptflag?

Yes. `fesetexceptflag` means: Set this exception flag to signify that an exception has been reported.

A correct usage of `fetestexcept` is:

```
feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
int mask = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
printf("current mask: %d\n",mask);
printf("FE_DIVBYZERO before: %s\n",std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO) ? "yes" : "no"); // no
double my_inf = one/zero;
int mask = fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
printf("current mask: %d\n",mask);
printf("FE_DIVBYZERO after: %s\n",std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO) ? "yes" : "no"); // yes
```

There is no standard way to make floating point exceptions raise a signal. That is the feature that glibc provides you. You can raise the signal yourself though:

```
if (fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT))
    raise(SIGFPE);
```

Comment: Ah, so the `fetestexcept` does not test "what exception will raise", but rather "what did already raised". Correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I misinterpreting the documentation of fesetexceptflag?

Yes. When you do for example `1.0/0` then the `FE_DIVBYZERO` flag *gets* raised in the current environment. `fesetexceptflag` doesn't let you decide what *will* happen when you divide by 0. `fesetexceptflag` let's you check *if* the operation that you already *did* resulted in exception.

You can only see what will happen on floating-point exceptions with [math_errhandling](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/math_errhandling) macro. Which is a macro that only tells that either `errno` or floating point exceptions are used.

This little example could shed some light:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cstdio>
#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS ON
#if math_errhandling != MATH_ERREXCEPT
   #error This code needs to use floating point exceptions
#endif

int main() {
    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT);
    printf("%s\n", std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO) ? "FE_DIVBYZERO" : "no FE_DIVBYZERO");
    double a = 1.0/0;
    printf("%s\n", std::fetestexcept(FE_DIVBYZERO) ? "FE_DIVBYZERO" : "no FE_DIVBYZERO");
}
```

will output:

```
no FE_DIVBYZERO
FE_DIVBYZERO
```

With `fexcept_t` you can restore *implementation defined representation* of currently set flags. You can't do `std::fexcept_t my_flag = FE_DIVBYZERO;` - well, you can, but the content of `fexcept_t` is implementation defined, so the result will be implementation-defined. You can't modify `fexcept_t` manually. You can only save currently raised floating point exceptions with `fegetexceptflag`, do some calculations that can throw that you want to inspect, and then restore the floating point exceptions with `fesetexceptflag` with the same flag. You modify `fexcept_t` by `sesetexceptflag` then with `feclearexcept` and `feraiseexcept` and then saving it with `fegetexceptflag`.

Throwing a `SIGFPE` signal is an extension [C99 J.5.17p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#J.5.17p1). It could happen in addition or instead of setting errno or floating point flags. The extension is activated with the gnu function `feenableexcept`.